# How to connect Android over wifi on a virtual usb?

Tags: usb, android

After stupidly messing around in factory-mode of my MTK Android phone, I lost both IMEI numbers (and all the secret files going with them). So the SIM cards are not detected any more.

Also, the micro-usb socket of the phone is physically broken. No data transfer and no charging. (I charge battery outside of the phone)

Of course I have tried out all the kinds of applications on the phone to restore or change IMEI number. But network radio is stubborn and will not activate. MTK engineer mode or Mobile uncle apk is not helping.

I ended up by finding and downloading two different MTK flash tools which are my last hope.

These applications are made for Windows and they seem to work well on Ubuntu via "Wine".

On my phone I have installed ADB Manager apk from "Ilija Matoski". This enables ADB commands from my PC via WiFi to the phone.

So far, so good...

Now I need Your help:

These MTK tools are supposed to work from a Windows PC via usb data cable.

Are there any commands I can use to

- keep a constant data exchange Android to PC (maybe unnecessary?); or
- to make the system (or just Wine) believe, that this wifi bridge is actually a plugged-in usb-Device ; or
- What-ever else to try

I am willing to try any workaround.
Just I am not a programmer, I don't know how to write command lines. But I know how to copy-paste them into terminal.

Please, help me with patience.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't give you an exact answer especially due to the broken usb port.

But you can try the following. Please note, the developer way of connecting to android devices is through the official adb tool provided by Google. I don't know what this applications your using are nor have I ever used vine.

Normal linux doesn't know android linux and there's no sudo command (besides something like sudo adb which isn't necessary). The Android Debug Bridge (ADB) is what connects to an android device on linux / Windows and is useful for flashing, browsing, installing, etc.

Connect to the device, identifying it by IP address.

```
$ adb connect <device-ip-address>
```

Confirm that your host computer is connected to the target device:

```
$ adb devices
```

List of devices attached
:5555 device

Unfortunately, the step before than requires the device to be plugged in via usb and I don't know if what you did can sidestep that...

Connect the device to the host computer with a USB cable.
Set the target device to listen for a TCP/IP connection on port 5555.

$ adb tcpip 5555

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

There's a lot more answers here where you might find something that works for you and it may be possible to do it without usb connecting first it seems but it looks like the device must be rooted to do so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327839/adb-over-wireless-without-usb-cable-at-all

Here someone says how to to it without usb for android 4.4 (possibly with a + but I don't see it on 5.1 so YMMV):
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67916/is-it-possible-to-adb-connect-android-via-wifi-without-configuring-port-on-andro

Comment: Thank You for this first answer.  You are right: tere is no Vine for Ubuntu! There is Wine.        I didn't know about TCP/IP. This hint made me find following articles: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless  and also  http://blog.avangardo.com/2012/12/null-modem-under-linux-wine/     Now I have to read there carefully and try to understand everything. Next I have to put all this together on my Ubuntu.   Could somebody please have a look at these links and tell me if I found what I need to learn? Or maybe give me ready to copy-paste lines for terminal?            Vlad